# Not getting updated hooks value inside function

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, setstate

Not getting updated value of state in function which gets triggered by eventListener. Even tried with background timer. What would be the problem?

```
displayIncomingCall() // this function gets called from UI.
```

```
const callApp = () => {
  const [calls, setCalls] = useState({});

  const addCall = (key, value) => {
    setCalls({ ...calls, [key]: value });
  };

  const displayIncomingCall = number => {
    const callUUID = getCurrentCallId();
    addCall(callUUID, number);
    ...
  };

  const onAnswerCall = () => {
    console.log('=== onAnswerCall ::: ===', calls); <--- always initial value. Not getting updated one.
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('=== useEffect ::: ===', calls); // getting updated value
  }, [calls]);

  useEffect(() => {
    RNCallKeep.addEventListener('answerCall', onAnswerCall);
    return () => {
      RNCallKeep.removeEventListener('answerCall', onAnswerCall);
    };
  }, []);

  console.log('=== parent ::: ===', calls); // getting updated value

  return (...)
}
```

Comment: That's because you only `addEventListener` once, when the component is first mounted, and don't update it when the component is re-rendered. It's always closed over the *initial* value of `calls`.

Comment: Please try add return in the setState

Answer (score 1):

`onAnswerCall` is only referenced in the `useEffect` callback, and the `useEffect` callback has an empty dependency array, so it only runs on the initial mount. Whenever `onAnswerCall` is called, the binding of `calls` that it can see is in an old closure.

Use a ref instead of state:

```
const callsRef = useRef({});
const addCall = (key, value) => {
  callsRef.current[key] = value;
};
const onAnswerCall = () => {
  console.log('=== onAnswerCall ::: ===', callsRef.current);
}
```

If `calls` *needs* to be in state so that its change results in a re-render, then you can either use *both* state and a ref, and assign to the ref when you call `setCalls`, or you can remove the dependency array from `useEffect`, thus adding and removing the listeners to `RNCallKeep` on each render.

Comment: This will work, but it won't re-render the component when updating the calls which I believe calls are used on component render so I asume it needs to trigger a re-render.

Comment: Since the return value of the component isn't seen, it's not clear if the component needs to re-render when a new call is made. If it does need to re-render, then like I said, one method is to use both a ref and state. Another is to add and remove the listener on each call.

Comment: The point of using state instead of normal variables, is to have React to trigger a component re-render. If you check my answer, the listener is updated (removed/added)  on each `onAnswerCall` `useCallback` update, which I believe is the best approach, that's the purpose of these hooks after all.

Comment: If a re-render is *necessary* when a variable changes, yes, of course use state - but from the code in the question it's not clear to me if such a re-render is needed. The component's returned JSX isn't shown, unfortunately

Comment: As of now, not using in render. It would be better if we have the flexibility of re-render as well. This solution works

Answer (score 1):

React hooks state does not persist any state data, you have to use `useCallback` and the previous state privided in the `set*`  state functions to keep up  with your state:

```js
const callApp = () => {
  const [calls, setCalls] = useState({});

  const addCall = (key, value) => {
    // Use previous state provided to update the state
    setCalls(calls => ({ ...calls, [key]: value }));
  };

  const displayIncomingCall = number => {
    const callUUID = getCurrentCallId();
    addCall(callUUID, number);
    ...
  };

  //  Use useCallback to keep up  with the  state
  const onAnswerCall = useCallback(() => {
    console.log('=== onAnswerCall ::: ===', calls); <--- Will get updated
  }, [calls]);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('=== useEffect ::: ===', calls); // getting updated value
  }, [calls]);

  useEffect(() => {
    RNCallKeep.addEventListener('answerCall', onAnswerCall);
    return () => {
      RNCallKeep.removeEventListener('answerCall', onAnswerCall);
    };
  }, [onAnswerCall]);

  console.log('=== parent ::: ===', calls); // getting updated value

  return (...)
}
```

Comment: but `onAnswerCall` is getting triggered multiple times (listener called only once)

Comment: The listener will unregister the old one and register a new one on each `calls` update, this won't affect how many times the `answerCall` event will get triggered and thus how many times `onAnswerCall` will be called by the event listener.

Comment: like `onAnswerCall` I have similar 4-5 call state event listeners as well which I haven't mentioned in the snippet. As I read https://kentcdodds.com/blog/usememo-and-usecallback
Will it effect performance if we use `useCallback` for all the event listeners?

Comment: *Every line of code which is executed comes with a cost* The performance hit you'll get is insignificant one extra function call per event for all the listeners. It's quite the case that when you call 2 functions instead of 1 there is much work to be done, isn't it? If you're just using these function to the listeners, place them directly inside the mount effect, otherwise you have no choise if you're using the `calls` state in your render method you'll have to use `useCallback`.

Answer (score 1):

Your event listener callback is closed over the initial state of `calls`. Add it as a dependency to the effect, and you should register a new listener (and remove old ones) each time its value changes.

**EDIT:** In reality, you should move the entire `onAnswerCall` function into the effect, since it is only used there:

```js
useEffect(() => {
  const onAnswerCall = () => {
    console.log('=== onAnswerCall ::: ===', calls);
  };

  RNCallKeep.addEventListener('answerCall', onAnswerCall);
  return () => {
    RNCallKeep.removeEventListener('answerCall', onAnswerCall);
  };
}, [calls]);
```

Comment: Why would you do that? You think `onAnswerCall` will be different after `calls` has changed?

Comment: @ChristosLytras it is a different function on every render, so yes! But it's return value is actually only different when `calls` changes. Here's a pen that illustrates this (look at the console): https://codesandbox.io/s/laughing-lehmann-4xe52?file=/src/App.js

Comment: My question was a bit miss-leading and I was refering to `calls` change state, not renders. I believe the correct way is to use `useCallback` and get a new function *only when* `calls` does change and then re-apply the listeners. Check your example with that logic here https://codesandbox.io/s/still-fast-x41jt?file=/src/App.js

Comment: I don't think we're disagreeing -- both solutions do the exact same thing (yours has fewer unnecessary creations of functions, but that's really fast in JS anyway). I was trying to point out OP's misunderstanding of how event listeners work.

Comment: These are not *unnecessary* creations of functions and this will result in actually **less** function creations because as you pointed out in your first comment about the new function on each render, we'll get a new function *only* when `calls` change and not on each render. Besides this, if you use *ESLint* with that effect you have in your answer, you'll get a notice about missing effect dependency for `onAnswerCall`.

Comment: I said yours has fewer (that means less).

Comment: Yes, my bad, I have issues reading today! Just keep my point about ESLint. Linter will complain about a missing dependency on the effect and if we supply the effect with the function without using `useCallback` we'll get an infinite loop re-render.

Comment: Yep. That's why I gave the answer I did. If you really know exactly how `useEffect` works, you can (in very narrow cases) ignore the linter warnings. This is one of them, since we know that our "missing dependency" will have necessarily been updated when our "proxy dependency" is. In real world, the best solution is to move `onAnswerCall` inside the effect, since it is only used there. This reduces complexity and encapsulates the concerns in the effect.

Comment: I disagree. In real world `useCallback` shoudl be used. This is a use case for it, that is why it exists, to refresh callback functions based on state dependencies. And I also disagree that this should be lint ignored. It should not be ignored and this is one of the cullprits of this OP issue and the linter will tell us there is something wrong there right away.

Comment: Have another look at my codepen, with the function moved inside the effect. No linter warnings. Does it encapsulate all this logic into one place? Yes. Does it do so using a single hook, instead of two, thus reducing code? Yes. Does it accurately convey what the point of the code is? Yes. There is, conceptually, a single dependency here. When `calls` changes, do stuff. Your method introduces indirection by creating a dependency chain which is harder to follow, and more brittle.

Comment: So you’re saying that all of the logic should be put inside one effect, and that this is a good thing? Really? Using hooks for the purpose they are made for is how the framework works. What if you need to access that function from outside the effect? It’s not “my method”, it’s how hooks update callback functions. Putting everything inside one effect is a way but not the way to go because you’re saying so. I suggest you read about [`useCallback`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecallback). Anyway I am out of this discussion. Have a nice day!

Comment: Agree to disagree, then. There's definitely a time and place for `useCallback`, and I absolutely use it daily. I just don't think you need it here since BOTH the effect and the function are depending on the same thing changing.